# Reading a Json Array from a snapshot to ember html page with no Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database, ember.js, handlebars.js

I set a bookmarks and favorites page of movies to a firebase at a movie profile page. Now I am trying to grab the information from only the ones that are bookmarked, grab the information (movieIds, titles, etc., and post that onto my html page. For some reason I cannot read in the information, my console.log shows me that the array is correct and has all the information I need, however I can't access it on the html page for some reason.
This is the bookmarks.js file

```
export default class BookmarksRoute extends Route {
  async model(params) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    //check if user is logged in
    if (user) {
      //first check if movie has been saved before
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref("users/" + user.uid + "/savedMovies/")
        .once("value", (snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
            //snapshot is returning the json for this particular movie saved by user id and putting it in userData
            const userData = snapshot.val();
            console.log("exists........", userData);
            var returnArr = [];
            snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
              var item = childSnapshot.val();
              item.key = childSnapshot.key;
              returnArr.push(item);
            });
            console.log("test", returnArr);
            console.log("Bookmarked: ", returnArr[0].isBookmarked);
            return returnArr;


          }
        });

    }
  }

}
```

This is the HTML file

```
<header class="bookmarks-header">
  <h1>BookMarks</h1>
</header>
<main class="bookmark-frame">
  <div class="ui four column grid">
    <div id="text">
      <h1>{{@model.title}}</h1>
      {{#each @model as |item|}}
      <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Examples of what prints on my console.log is

```
0: {adult: false, isBookmarked: true, isFavorited: false, movieID: 41586, poster_path: "/1ZsF9u6bBp46mMXTOpSAqowlZW4.jpg", …}
1: {isBookmarked: false, isFavorited: true, movieID: 337401, poster_path: "/aKx1ARwG55zZ0GpRvU2WrGrCG9o.jpg", release_date: "2020-09-04", …}
2: {isBookmarked: true, isFavorited: false, movieID: 497358, poster_path: "/kQp149wW9XN7lEH5B3xkKpkzYGT.jpg", release_date: "1969-12-25", …}
3: {isBookmarked: false, isFavorited: true, movieID: 577922, poster_path: "/k68nPLbIST6NP96JmTxmZijEvCA.jpg", release_date: "2020-08-22", …}
4: {isBookmarked: false, isFavorited: true, movieID: 590706, poster_path: "/eLT8Cu357VOwBVTitkmlDEg32Fs.jpg", release_date: "2020-11-20", …}
5: {isBookmarked: true, isFavorited: false, movieID: 671583, poster_path: "/xfYMQNApIIh8KhpNVtG1XRz0ZAp.jpg", release_date: "2020-07-31", …}
6: {isBookmarked: true, isFavorited: false, movieID: 729648, poster_path: "/6OeGqp18oZucUGziMIRNhLouZ75.jpg", release_date: "2020-11-02", …}
[]: (...)
firstObject: (...)
hasArrayObservers: (...)
lastObject: (...)
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Export of my JSON file looks like:

```
{
  "CfWjFzxOWBfFbfc80NFmktwFJye2" : {
    "savedMovies" : {
      "454433" : {
        "isBookmarked" : true,
        "isFavorited" : false,
        "movieID" : 454433,
        "poster_path" : "/awcPLFFYjufRXd2oAAP6ZIXF9vM.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2020-08-14",
        "title" : "Magic Camp",
        "vote_average" : 7
      },
      "524047" : {
        "isBookmarked" : false,
        "isFavorited" : true,
        "movieID" : 524047,
        "poster_path" : "/bNo2mcvSwIvnx8K6y1euAc1TLVq.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2020-07-29",
        "title" : "Greenland",
        "vote_average" : 7.2
      },
      "524087" : {
        "isBookmarked" : false,
        "isFavorited" : true,
        "movieID" : 524087,
        "poster_path" : "/3rRUp4WZdvt4LfdXIWL0qmFv9UI.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2018-11-02",
        "title" : "Dear Ex",
        "vote_average" : 7.4
      },
      "590706" : {
        "isBookmarked" : true,
        "isFavorited" : true,
        "movieID" : 590706,
        "poster_path" : "/eLT8Cu357VOwBVTitkmlDEg32Fs.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2020-11-20",
        "title" : "Jiu Jitsu",
        "vote_average" : 5.7
      },
      "602211" : {
        "isBookmarked" : true,
        "isFavorited" : false,
        "movieID" : 602211,
        "poster_path" : "/4n8QNNdk4BOX9Dslfbz5Dy6j1HK.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2020-11-13",
        "title" : "Fatman",
        "vote_average" : 6.1
      },
      "654028" : {
        "isBookmarked" : true,
        "isFavorited" : false,
        "movieID" : 654028,
        "poster_path" : "/6sG0kbEvAi3RRLcGGU5h8l3qAPa.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2020-11-18",
        "title" : "The Christmas Chronicles: Part Two",
        "vote_average" : 7.1
      },
      "724989" : {
        "isBookmarked" : true,
        "isFavorited" : true,
        "movieID" : 724989,
        "poster_path" : "/ugZW8ocsrfgI95pnQ7wrmKDxIe.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2020-10-23",
        "title" : "Hard Kill",
        "vote_average" : 5
      },
      "726208" : {
        "isBookmarked" : false,
        "isFavorited" : true,
        "movieID" : 726208,
        "poster_path" : "/ffdPUteSePSqJEhKJKwgSIWumC2.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2020-07-24",
        "title" : "Don't Listen",
        "vote_average" : 6.7
      }
    }
  },
  "uY5GV5VCMbPufW4eVQChh61sbOC2" : {
    "savedMovies" : {
      "41586" : {
        "adult" : false,
        "isBookmarked" : true,
        "isFavorited" : false,
        "movieID" : 41586,
        "poster_path" : "/1ZsF9u6bBp46mMXTOpSAqowlZW4.jpg",
        "release_date" : "1999-12-07",
        "title" : "K-911",
        "vote_average" : 5.5
      },
      "337401" : {
        "isBookmarked" : false,
        "isFavorited" : true,
        "movieID" : 337401,
        "poster_path" : "/aKx1ARwG55zZ0GpRvU2WrGrCG9o.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2020-09-04",
        "title" : "Mulan",
        "vote_average" : 7.2
      },
      "497358" : {
        "isBookmarked" : true,
        "isFavorited" : false,
        "movieID" : 497358,
        "poster_path" : "/kQp149wW9XN7lEH5B3xkKpkzYGT.jpg",
        "release_date" : "1969-12-25",
        "title" : "Ave, Vita",
        "vote_average" : 6.8
      },
      "577922" : {
        "isBookmarked" : false,
        "isFavorited" : true,
        "movieID" : 577922,
        "poster_path" : "/k68nPLbIST6NP96JmTxmZijEvCA.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2020-08-22",
        "title" : "Tenet",
        "vote_average" : 7.4
      },
      "590706" : {
        "isBookmarked" : false,
        "isFavorited" : true,
        "movieID" : 590706,
        "poster_path" : "/eLT8Cu357VOwBVTitkmlDEg32Fs.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2020-11-20",
        "title" : "Jiu Jitsu",
        "vote_average" : 5.7
      },
      "671583" : {
        "isBookmarked" : true,
        "isFavorited" : false,
        "movieID" : 671583,
        "poster_path" : "/xfYMQNApIIh8KhpNVtG1XRz0ZAp.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2020-07-31",
        "title" : "Upside-Down Magic",
        "vote_average" : 7.7
      },
      "729648" : {
        "isBookmarked" : true,
        "isFavorited" : false,
        "movieID" : 729648,
        "poster_path" : "/6OeGqp18oZucUGziMIRNhLouZ75.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2020-11-02",
        "title" : "The Dalton Gang",
        "vote_average" : 4.7
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "my console.log shows me that the array is correct and has all the information I need" We have no way to see that. Please edit your question to include the JSON at `users/$uid/savedMovies/` (as text, no screensdhots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).